# Can I reduce this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, reduction

Can I reduce

```
function n()
  {
  var a; 
  if(a = document.getElementById('fb0')) 
    {
    a.onclick = i0;
    document.getElementById('fb1').onclick = i1;
    }
  }
```

to

```
function n()
  {
  if(document.getElementById('fb0').onclick = i0) 
    {
    document.getElementById('fb1').onclick = i1;
    }
  }
```

I don't have a debugger right now.  I know that `document.getElementById('fb0')` returns a value because the first snippet works fine.  But does it need the assignment to be evaluated in the if statement?

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to do assignment in your conditional? Or is that a double equals error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

`document.getElementById('fb0')`, as the function name already says, returns the `html element` with has the id equal to `fb0`. After that you are accessing the attribute `onclick`. But it the get fails it will break the script.

On the first scenario you test if the assignment works, if does it means the element exists and will only execute if it exists.

Those are different behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

Not really; if `getElementById('fb0')` doesn't return anything your page will get an error, and in the first case it wouldn't.

Comment: As a side note, I'd strongly recommend against using "tricks" for minimizing JS, including the assignment in the condition - that will likely cause headaches for maintenance later. You can use some JS minifier if you're worried about download size.

Comment: It removes some unnecessary spaces / comments, sometimes shortens variable names, and it can potentially (although I don't know if the existing ones do) apply some code changes which don't change the semantics of the program, all to reduce the size of the JS file. Some examples are at http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html or http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/34488

Answer (score 1):

To check if "document.getElementById('fb0')" returns an element or null, the second version don't do it and an error will be throw if there is no element with id "fb0". The second version is ok if you don't remove the "fb0" element from the DOM at some point.

Answer (score 0):

That would fail if `document.getElementById('fb0')` were not to exist. `document.getElementById('fb0').onclick` wouldn't mean much in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a lot of DOM selection by ID, make a shortened version of that method:

```
function byId( id ) { return document.getElementById(id); };

function n() {
  var a; 
  if(a = byId('fb0')) {
    a.onclick = i0;
    byId('fb1').onclick = i1;
  }
}
```

In this case, doing the assignment inside the condition doesn't save you any characters. It's the same length to do it with the declaration.

```
function byId( id ) { return document.getElementById(id); };

function n() {
  var a = byId('fb0'); 
  if(a) {
    a.onclick = i0;
    byId('fb1').onclick = i1;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to weigh the cost of a second function vs. characters saved.  Correct?

Comment: @Chris Aaker: Absolutely. But unless you're doing some insane DOM selection in a loop or something, you'll never notice the difference. And in my opinion, you should really just use that method once for any given element. If that same element is needed again, you should cache the result. So for example if some element is fetched in a function, you'd cache it the first time the function is invoked, and subsequent invocations would use the cached element.